# Echo Array into new lines

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an edit page where a user can edit an invoice form. I need to echo the array into a table but separate each array into a new line on the table.

When i echo the value, its bunched up into one line. When i echo the value into an input field, i only get one record from the array.

Here's what it looks like in my table:

[image]

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE id=$id");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

$partnumber = $res['partnumber'];

$partdescription = $res['partdescription'];

$partprice = $res['partprice'];

$partquantity = $res['partquantity'];


}
>
```

And then the table:

```
<tr>

    <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="partnumber[]" value=<?php echo $partnumber;?>></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="partdescription[]" value=<?php echo $partdescription;?>></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="partprice[]" size="4" value=<?php echo $partprice;?>></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="partquantity[]" size="4" value=<?php echo $partquantity;?>></td>


</tr>
```

I get this:
[image]

```
 <tr>

    <td><?php echo $partnumber;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $partdescription;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $partprice;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $partquantity;?></td>


</tr>
```

I get this:
[image]

I tried the following but they both result in a blank echo:

```
<tr>
<td><? echo $res['partnumber']; ?></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><? echo $res['partdescription']; ?></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><? echo $res['partprice']; ?></td>
</tr><tr>
<td><? echo $res['partquantity']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

And

```
<? foreach ($res as $row) { ?>
<tr>
<td><? echo $row['partnumber']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row['partdescription']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row['partprice']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row['partquantity']; ?></td>
</tr>
<? 
 }
 ?>
```

This is the GOAL:
[image]

Please help

EDIT***************

I will fix the security issue once i have the table working.

I tried this and the output is still on ONE line.

```
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];


$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."' ");


while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
 <tr>
  <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="partnumber[]" value=<?php echo $res['partnumber'];?>></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="partdescription[]" value=<?php echo $res['partdescription'];?>></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="partprice[]" size="4" value=<?php echo $res['partprice'];?>></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="partquantity[]" size="4" value=<?php echo $res['partquantity'];?>></td>
```

```
<?php
}
?>
```

Does this help?

[image]

[image]

Please note, its only displaying 1 record because i have multiple values in one record and them i'm separating them with a comma. Please check screenshots above. Here's the code:

```
$partnumber = $_POST['partnumber'];
$partnumberarray = implode( ", ", $partnumber);


$partdescription = $_POST['partdescription'];
$partdescriptionarray = implode( ", ", $partdescription);


$partprice = $_POST['partprice'];
$partpricearray = implode( ", ", $partprice);


$partquantity = $_POST['partquantity'];
$partquantityarray = implode( ", ", $partquantity);



$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO invoicespartnumber, partdescription, partprice, partquantity, login_id) VALUES('$partnumberarray', '$partdescriptionarray', '$partpricearray', '$partquantityarray', '$loginId')");
```

Is there anyway i can echo the values from the 1 record which is separated by a comma into multiple lines on the table?

Comment: You specified `ID` in mysql statement. Are you sure that has more than one record ?

Comment: *Security warning*: Your PHP is injectable. Be extremely careful when using SQL queries like that. Consider page.php?id=0 or drop table ..

Comment: @user1235709 Can you give us more detail about your mysql table please. Especially, I really want to see your `ID`

Comment: does that help @Natsathorn

Comment: @user1235709 I guess you got one record because of `Where clause` you declare only one id. Try remove that.

Comment: @user1235709 try this query `SELECT * FROM invoices`

Comment: Ah that worked, i only wanted to pull the parts from a particular invoice thou, not all of them. Hmmm

Comment: but you will get only one record if you specified `ID`.

Comment: Its one record but i have multiple entries in there seperated by a comma. For example, in the table its listed like this part1, part2, part3

Comment: Sounds like you've only got 1 row in your database; You don't need to separate anything by commas.

Comment: So when the user is adding parts to the database, i have them adding multipe parts to one record but then we separate them but a comma. Please check the original post, i'm going to edit it.

Comment: Use another table in that case - don't separate things with commas. Have one row per part on each invoice. select * from partsOnInvoices where invoice={invoiceID}. If you must though, see PHP's explode(',',$row['partnumber']).

Comment: Can i explode it into multiple lines on a table thou? I dont want everything on one line

Comment: Explode returns an array which you can loop through (and in your loop, generate as many table rows as you want). I guess you're quite new to PHP so you might want to play around with looping/ arrays to get the hang of those first, but you'll also want to change the structure of your database too. Table for invoices, table for parts, table for parts on each invoice. Loop through rows from that last one.

Comment: You are fighting against a poorly designed table structure.  Take Luke's advice.  Better to have two tables. Or else have one table with one column for Invoice# and another column for Row#, then you will have two identifiers for each row of the invoice -- then you can just query for the Invoice# and loop through the Row#s.  All this messing around with commas and arrays is unnecessary complication.

Comment: I'll add another table for parts. The parts table will have the information for the table and then the id for the invoice and id of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your html inside while loop that you do over result array.

It will look like this.

```
 <?php

 $id = $_GET['id'];

 $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE ID='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."'");

 while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ //close php here to easier write html. ?> 
 <tr>
      <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="partnumber[]" value="<?php echo $res['partnumber'];?>"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="partdescription[]" value="<?php echo $res['partdescription'];?>"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="partprice[]" size="4" value="<?php echo $res['partprice'];?>"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="input-small" name="partquantity[]" size="4" value="<?php echo $res['partquantity'];?>"></td>
 </tr>

 <?php //open php tag again to add end scope to while loop
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: It would be wise to fix the injection security issue - somebody could cause **a lot** of damage with this. Specifically:

WHERE ID='".mysql_real_escape_string($id)."'"

.. but it's strongly advisable to use the safer mysqli functions instead.

Comment: I will fix the security issue as soon as i get the table working.

Comment: @user1235709 please reply me. I wrote my question into your post comments

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width = "100%">
<thead>
<tr>
// here will be all columns names in th
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

$id = $_GET['id'];

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE id=$id");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{ ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $res['partnumber']; ?></td> <!-- Also use input box here -->

<td><?php echo $res['partdescription'];?><td>

<td><?php echo  $res['partprice']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo  $res['partquantity'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```